# Resizing textbox in the Yii2 form

Tags: php, yii2

I am following a tutorial and it is using bootstrap. I am not sure how I would resize textbox for `Lan_Id`, `Name` and `Employee_Number` in it. I think, I am starting to understand Yii framework.

Here is the view `userForm.php`:

```
<?php

    use yii\helpers\HTML;
    use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

    ?>
    <?php
        if(Yii::$app->session->hasFlash('success'))
        {
            echo Yii::$app->session->getFlash('success');
        }
    ?>
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin();?>
    <?= $form->field($model,'Lan_Id');?>
    <?= $form->field($model,'Name');?>
    <?= $form->field($model,'Employee_Number');?>
    <?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class'=>'btn btn-success']);
```

Here is the model `UserForm.php`:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use yii\base\Model;

class UserForm extends Model
{

    public $Lan_Id;
    public $Name;
    public $Employee_Number;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['Lan_Id','Name','Employee_Number'],'required'],
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want to change the input text field length:

```
 <?= $form->field($model,'Lan_Id')->textInput(['maxlength'=>10]);?>
```

Above code limits the maximum length of characters to 10.

But if you want to change the input text field size:

```
 <?= $form->field($model,'Lan_Id')->textInput(['style'=>'width:100px']);?>
```

Above code changes the input text field width to `100px`. You can also have both:

```
 <?= $form->field($model,'Lan_Id')->textInput(['maxlength'=>10,'style'=>'width:100px']);?>
```

It is highly recommended to take a look at `Yii2`'s official document: **http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activefield.html**

Comment: @Veronica You're welcome dear. Yii is really powerful. I hope you will enjoy coding with Yii.

Comment: `<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options'=>['style'=>'width:500px;margin:0px auto;']]); ?>`